# How to register log file from shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running apache2, and I've connected scripts with the html, I want to register all the echo outputs in a file named user.log.
I've tried LOG_LOCATION="path" and it didn't works

```
> #!/bin/bash
opcion=$(php -r "echo urldecode('$QUERY_STRING');" | sed -n 's/^.*cmd=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p')
NombreProceso=$(php -r "echo urldecode('$QUERY_STRING');" | sed -n 's/^.*name=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p')

Fecha=$(date)

echo "-Procesos-" >> user.log

if [ $opcion == "1" ];then

sudo kill $NombreProceso -s SIGHUP
echo "$Fecha::Paramos el proceso $NombreProceso" >> **user.log**
fi 

if [ $opcion == "2" ];then
sudo kill $NombreProceso -s SIGSTOP 
echo "$Fecha::Pausamos el proceso $NombreProceso" >> **user.log**
fi

echo Content-Type: text/html
echo -e "

<html>
    <head>
        <title> UOLS WEB Unai Ayoub Jaime</title>

    </head>
    <body>"

echo -e "<textarea style='width:100%;height:90%; resize: none' disabled>"

        ps -e

        echo -e "</textarea>"
echo -e "
    </body>
</html>
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did that in

```
echo "-Procesos-" >> user.log
```

Add ">> user.log" to all other echos commands